# Show layout on clicking an item in Actionbar - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

My activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"       
    tools:context="com.myactionbar.actionbar.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <!-- Enable this layout on clicking the icon in actionbar -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_ListView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" 
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:visibility="invisible">               
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main.xml - It shows an icon at actionbar

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/show_info"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
        />
```

On clicking the `ic_icon` icon in actionbar, i need to show the hidden `Relativelayout` with `id=rl_ListView1`.

I don't know how to find the layout with id on clicking an item in actionbar.

Please help me to do this.

Comment: you can find this `item` in `onOptionsItemSelected` method

Comment: in `onOptionsItemSelected()` get the clicked item and show your layout by using yourlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override onOptionsItemSelected method in our activity

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {

        //Code for showing layout
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

=========
Updated

```
if (id == R.id.show_info) {

if(r1.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
{ 
               //Hide your layout
}
else
{
  //Show your layout
}
```

Comment: RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_ListView1); get the Relatielayout with id. How to set the visiblity of Layout to True.

Comment: You can do this by rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: and use if (id == R.id.show_info) instead of  if (id == android.R.id.home)

Comment: Is it possible to do the like this "on clicking the icon 1st time show the layout and again on click to hide the layout and vise versa. If possible please send me the tutorial link or sample link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()` in your activity . For e.g:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.show_info:
          // Change visibilty of your RelativeLayout here
             if(rl.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                rl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             }else{
                rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_ListView1); get the Relatielayout with id. How to set the visiblity of Layout to True.

Comment: like this : `rl.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE)`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    try {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu:
            //do here
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log(e);
    }
}
```